# Can we custom whole Django Admin site is it possible?

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible to do anything in the `django-admin` site? I mean can we custom it according to our needs??

Comment: if you want whole django admin site custom then why not make your own custom admin panel?

Comment: From Review: Which customization? What do you want exactly to achieve? Please be more specific, your question is still too broad.

Comment: [Here's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/) all the details you need to know about customisation of the django admin site. If this is not what you're looking for, please specify what you are exactly trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`django-admin` is an application added to the default django projects. As you can see in `settings.py` file, there's `'django.contrib.admin'` and `'django.contrib.auth'` (which contains user management models and logics) in the `INSTALLED_APPS` array. You can get rid of them if you want and add your-own developed alternative apps instead. But `django-admin` is a powerful tool and there's many guides to custom it's functionalities. For example [django admin cookbook](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/) is a famous one.

It's all dependent on what you want and need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, you can start copying whole /your_python_directory/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin to your local template directory. (defined in your settings.py)